# Jquery- Same object, multiple clicks, multiple functions

Tags: jquery, function, click

I'm trying to figure out the best way to achieve an effect of clicking on object1 once and causing a function once (animating object A), then clicking on object1 again and causing another function (animating another object-B), etc.

Can someone please toss me a few terminologies for what to use here? I do know how to achieve animation via jQuery/CSS add/remove/toggle class but I'm looking for the most efficient approach.

Comment: If you just want to toggle between two functions (first will be executed on first click, second will be executed on second click, then first again and so on..) then you can you the jQuery.toggle() function.

Comment: I guess a better way of describing the effect is of a gun shooting multiple bullets- 1-red, 2-blue, 3-green. Each time you click the gun it fires one of the 3 bullets...sorry I don't have enough working to show an example!

Comment: Then you can go by the example given by @andrewdotnich, but you'll have to be careful with it because it can bind multiple click events if you don't use it properly. Otherwise, you can keep a counter, and check it's value on each click and then execute the appropriate function according to it.

Comment: I updated my answer, I think this does what you need…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for JQuery 'one-shot' event handlers.

http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
function first() {
    $('#a').animate();
};

function next() {
    $('#b').animate();
};

$('#button').one('click', function() {
    first();
    $('#button').click(next);
};
```

This runs the `first` function the first time the click event is fired, and then re-binds the click event to the `next` function for all subsequent clicks.

**EDIT:** Alternately, if you have two and want them to alternate, you can use Vishal's suggestion of `toggle`: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

**EDIT 2**:

Another alternative is to keep a counter in the event handler, like so:

```
function fireA() { /*...*/ }
function fireB() { /*...*/ }
function fireC() { /*...*/ }

$('#button').click(function() {
   var events = [fireA, fireB, fireC];

   //declare counter
   if(!this.counter) { this.counter = 0; }

   events[this.counter]();
   this.counter = (this.counter + 1) % 3;
});
```

Comment: I am having a blast w/ this second edit alternative- thanks andrewdotnich!

Comment: A further refactoring: if the mechanics of the events are the same, but happen to different elements/objects, you could rewrite this so that the handler calls a single function, passing the element/object to be animated as a parameter. Then you can simply keep an array of potential parameters to the function, not references to functions…

Comment: Noted. The events are indeed a bit different- ending in different locations for each. The only remaining factor is that there is an if clause I'm working out- if a class is true on an object, then function fireA, etc....if class on function is false, the 'bullets' will simply fade. Getting there! Thanks for you help.